# Getting the namespace where a form is called

Tags: clojure

I would like a macro `this-ns` such that it returns the namespace of the location where it is being called. For instance, if I have this code

```
(ns nstest.main
  (:require [nstest.core :as nstest]))

(defn ns-str [x]
  (-> x (.getName) name))

(defn -main [& args]
  (println "The ns according to *ns*:" (ns-str *ns*))
  (println "The actual ns:" (ns-str (nstest/this-ns))))
```

I would expect that calling `lein run` would produce this output:

```
The ns according to *ns*: user
The actual ns: nstest.main
```

What I came up with as implementation was the following code:

```
(ns nstest.core)

(defmacro this-ns []
  (let [s (gensym)]
    `(do (def ~s)
         (-> (var ~s)
             (.ns)))))
```

It does seem to work, but it feels very hacky. Notably, in the above example it will expand to `def` being invoked *inside* the `-main` function which does not feel very clean.

**My question**: Is there a better way to implement `this-ns` to obtain the namespace where `this-ns` is called?

Comment: I'll just note that I found [this](https://clojureverse.org/t/when-i-use-lein-run-why-does-it-launch-in-the-user-namespace/3513).

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thanks. Following the link, what Sean Corfield suggests seems effective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting question.  I would never have guessed that your code would output `user` for the first println statement.

The problem is that only the Clojure compiler knows the name of an NS, and that is only when a source file is being compiled.  This information is lost before any functions in the NS are called at runtime.  That is why we get `user` from the code:  apparently lein calls `demo.core/-main` from the `user` ns.

The only way to save the NS information so it is accessible at runtime (vs compile time) is to force an addition to the NS under a known name, as you did with your `def` in the macro.  This is similar to Sean's trick (from [Carcingenicate's link](https://clojureverse.org/t/when-i-use-lein-run-why-does-it-launch-in-the-user-namespace/3513)):

```
 (def ^:private my-ns *ns*)   ; need to paste this into *each* ns
```

The only other approach I could think of was to somehow get the Java call stack, so we could find out who called our "get-ns" function.  Of course, Java provides a simple way to examine the call stack:

```
(ns demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core)
  (:require
    [clojure.string :as str]))

(defn caller-ns-func []
  (let [ex                (RuntimeException. "dummy")
        st                (.getStackTrace ex)
        class-names       (mapv #(.getClassName %) st)
        class-name-this   (first class-names)
        class-name-caller (first
                            (drop-while #(= class-name-this %)
                              class-names))

        ; class-name-caller is like "tst.demo.core$funky"
        [ns-name fn-name] (str/split class-name-caller #"\$")]
    (vals->map ns-name fn-name)))
```

and usage:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [clojure.string :as str]
    [demo.core :as core]))

(defn funky [& args]
  (spyx (core/caller-ns-func)))

(dotest
  (funky))
```

with result:

```
(core/caller-ns-func) => {:ns-name "tst.demo.core", :fn-name "funky"}
```

And we didn't even need a macro!

Comment: I tried this and can confirm that it is effective. Great that I don't need a macro.

Answer (score 6):

here is one more variant:

```
(defmacro this-ns []
  `(->> (fn []) str (re-find #"^.*?(?=\$|$)") symbol find-ns))
```

the thing is the anonymous function is compiled to a class named something like 
`playground.core$_main$fn__181@27a0a5a2`, so it starts with the name of the actual namespace the function gets compiled in.

Can't say it looks any less hacky, then your variant, still it avoids the side effect, introduced by `def` in your case.